# Perform Multiple Async Method Calls Sequentially

Tags: c#, async-await

It seems like I have come across the answer to this question in the past but now I cannot locate it.

Suppose I have two asynchronous methods, Method1 and Method2.  If I need to call Method1 and then Method2 sequentially (read, Method1 must complete before Method2), is the following code correct?

```
await Method1();
await Method2();
```

Based on information from the accepted answer to another SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445279/multiple-awaits-in-a-single-method) and information in the MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx), I believe this is the correct way to do it.  Also, this code appears to work but I don't want to introduce a subtle bug that will be much harder to track down later.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct way. They will execute sequentially.

The important quote from the msdn:

> The await operator tells the compiler that the async method **can't continue past that point** until the awaited asynchronous process is complete.

*If you wanted* to execute them in parallel, you'd have to use something like this:

```
var t1 = DoTaskAsync(...);
var t2 = DoTaskAsync(...);
var t3 = DoTaskAsync(...);

await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3);
```

Answer (score 9):

I know this thread is a bit old, but I'd like to add an issue I ran into using async methods.

This is purely for insight, and something I figured out by trial-and-error.

If you create a `void()` method, you cannot `await` it unless you call the method like this:

```
await Task.Run(() => Method());
```

...with the method declaration:

```
void Method() {...}
```

Calling the function using `await Task.Run` executes multiple methods without waiting for any previous functions to execute.

If for example you have:

```
void Method1() {...}
void Method2() {...}
void Method3() {...}
```

And you call them like this:

```
await Task.Run(() => Method1());
await Task.Run(() => Method2());
await Task.Run(() => Method3());
```

The await operation won't wait for Method1 to finish before calling Method2 etc.

To overcome this, create the function like this:

```
async Task Method1() {...}
async Task Method2() {...}
async Task Method3() {...}
```

And call them like this:

```
await Method1();
await Method2();
await Method3();
```

Comment: TL;DR Avoid void async https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45447955/why-exactly-is-void-async-bad