# C# executing function after async function is finished executing

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have to execute a batch process. The Ids are generated and stored in a list. I need to execute the function only after all the Ids are generated. The issue is these Ids are generated inside async function. And because I am using a third party API, marking this function async is mandatory. Here is the code:

```
static void SaveFiles()
{
    try
    {
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                //The following is async function.
                MakeAnalysisRequest(file.FullName, file.Name);
            }

            //The following needs to be called only after the MakeAnalysisRequest function has populated "Ids"
            if (Ids.Count > 1)
                CallBatchProcess(Ids);

            Console.WriteLine("Processing images...");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("There was an error! ");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async void MakeAnalysisRequest(string imageFilePath, string fileName)
{
    //Here a list is populated.
    //List<string> Ids = new List<string();
    Ids.Add(obj.Id);
}
```

Comment: What's `Ids`? Where is it declared? Why are you returning `void` instead of `Task<int>` or `Task<List<int>>`? Do you even know how `async void` works? And how is it that marking the function `async` is mandatory? You cannot enforce that in c#

Comment: if you have no await statement in your async method, then it will be executed **synchronously**. In this case you don't have to worry because after the loop all method calls will be finished

Comment: [`async void` isn't recommended.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45447955/why-exactly-is-void-async-bad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without an `await` in your async `MakeAnalysisRequest` it will be executed synchronously. If this is the case, all calls will end and your method will be executed after all.

But if `MakeAnalysisRequest` has an `await` statement, making it asynchronous, you could create a `Task` array and wait them all.

First change your method to return a `Task`

```
static async Task MakeAnalysisRequest(string imageFilePath, string fileName)
{
    //Here a list is populated.
    // Some await statement
    //List<string> Ids = new List<string();
    Ids.Add(obj.Id);
}

static void SaveFiles()
{
    try
    {
            var tasks = new List<Task>();

            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                //The following is async function.
                tasks.Add(MakeAnalysisRequest(file.FullName, file.Name));
            }

            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

            //The following needs to be called only after the MakeAnalysisRequest function has populated "Ids"
            if (Ids.Count > 1)
                CallBatchProcess(Ids);

            Console.WriteLine("Processing images...");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("There was an error! ");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Obviously the posted code is not the entire function. Why are you guessing whether `await` is used or not instead of waiting for the OP to add more details?

Comment: @MickyD why no? It will be executed synchronously indeed.

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand you don't need to execute the method asynchronously. You just need to make a call to a asynchronous method. If that's the case you could simply use Wait() on the asynchronous call for your **MakeAnalysisRequest** method or even better, for the api method that you're calling.

```cs
    static void SaveFiles()
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                //The following is async function.
                MakeAnalysisRequest(file.FullName, file.Name).Wait(); // The only change
            }

            //The following needs to be called only after the MakeAnalysisRequest function has populated "Ids"
            if (Ids.Count > 1)
                CallBatchProcess(Ids);

            Console.WriteLine("Processing images...");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There was an error! ");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void async MakeAnalysisRequest(string imageFilePath, string fileName)
    {
        //Here a list is populated.
        //List Ids = new List();
        Ids.Add(obj.Id);
    }
```

It's important to note that this is going to make the call synchronous (it will wait until the asynchronous call is finished). If you intend to execute it asynchronously for real you'd need to change the way your application is implemented to keep it executing until an action to finish it is performed.

Answer (score 0):

Make it MakeAnalysisRequest as Task. And call you that with multiple threads like

```
tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MakeAnalysisRequest(fullName, name)));
```

And Wait for all thread completion and you can process with other code.

Code Sample:

```
static void SaveFiles(){
    List<Tasks> tasks = new List<Task>();
        try
        {
                foreach (FileInfo file in files)
                {
                    //The following is async function.
                    string fullName=file.FullName;
                    string name=file.Name;
                    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MakeAnalysisRequest(fullName, name)));
                }
                Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
                //The following needs to be called only after the MakeAnalysisRequest function has populated "Ids"
                if (Ids.Count > 1)
                    CallBatchProcess(Ids);

                Console.WriteLine("Processing images...");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There was an error! ");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task MakeAnalysisRequest(string imageFilePath, string fileName)
    {
        //Here a list is populated.
        //List<string> Ids = new List<string();
        Ids.Add(obj.Id);
    }
```