# Task.Run() doesn't raise exception?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following code in the

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Task.Run(async () => await Presenter.Search());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LabelMessage.Text = "Error:....";
    }
}
```

The function `Presenter.Search()` may get exceptions in some cases and I want to show an error message. However, the exception is not raised? I can only see it in the Visual studio debugger.

Comment: It runs async, you're not `await`ing it, how is the `Task.Run` supposed to throw a exception which happens somewhen in the future?

Answer (score 4):

Really this should be written like so:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await Presenter.Search();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LabelMessage.Text = "Error:....";
    }
}
```

Now the call is awaited and the exception will be handled correctly. Note that you shouldn't typically use `async void` for the reasons listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45447955/why-exactly-is-void-async-bad), but in the case of UI event handlers it's the recommended approach.

Comment: My code is more complex than that. The code is actually kicked up by a timer in constructor. I think I will need to post a new question

Comment: @ca9163d9 I think so too.  Your question needs to accurately match what you need to do, as well as describe the circumstances involved (the timer).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if `Presenter.Search` already returns a `Task` you should consider to make the event handler `async` and simply put

```
await Presenter.Search();
```

in the try-catch block.

The reason of `Task.Run(Func<Task>)` overload exists is that you can force an already existing `Task` to be scheduled for execution on a pool thread. This case can be justified in very rare cases as normally you should rely on the internal implementation of the `Task` returning methods. But if you know that an async method does not use threads (for example, just returns a `Task`, which will be completed on a specific event) and you are confident enough about forcing the execution on a pool thread you can do it this way. But also in this case you should await the external task; otherwise, the call is fire-and-forget and you will not catch anything:

```
await Task.Run(() => Presenter.Search());
```

Please note that I omitted the inner async-await:

```
await Task.Run(async () => await Presenter.Search());
```

This would also work and is functionally equivalent to the previous version but adds a needless inner state machine to the chain of tasks to execute.

TL;DR: Without knowing any further details `await Presenter.Search();` seems to be the better solution but also `await Task.Run(() => Presenter.Search());` can be justified if you know what you are doing.