# UI Blocking in Async method

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to show a form and at the same time upload some data. I'm looking at how to do it with `async` and `await`, but I'm still blocking the UI.

Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Async
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public async void Init()
        {
            Text = "Setting Form Caption";
            label1.Text = "Setting label1 text";
            label2.Text = "Setting label2 text";

            var res = await GetData();
            res.ForEach(r => listBox1.Items.Add(r));
        }

        async Task<List<int>> GetData()
        {
            await Task.Delay(200);
            List<int> lTmp = new List<int>();

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                foreach (var t in Enumerable.Range(1, 10000))
                    lTmp.Add(t);

            });
            return lTmp;
        }
    }
}
```

This code is called at Button click inside another form with this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    frm.Init();
    frm.Show();
}
```

Executing this, I have 2 questions:

1. If I remove `Task.Delay(200)` from the `GetData()` method, I can't see the text of the labels until the data has finished loading.
2. I can't move the Form2 until the `GetData()` is finished

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Or should I take some other approach?

Comment: Async all the way. The button1_Click handler must be async, and await the call to Init.

Comment: `async void`  [:(](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45447955/9363973)

Comment: Well async void is not bad ... It is just fire and forget... His problem here is that assigning values to controls means it has to run on the UI thread.

Comment: do what @CodeCaster said call the init function with await and add async to the event handler also return a Task from init not void. void and async are fine with event handlers only

Comment: @LegacyCode you cant await a function that doesn't return a Task

Comment: Yes ... That’s why it is called fire and forget.

Comment: Async void is *always* bad. Because you cannot await a function that doesn't return a task. Meaning exceptions can (and will) be lost. I highly recommend watching Brandon Minnick's [talk about async/ await](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0mcYVxJEl0). Instead of async void, use `async Task`. The only exception should be `EventHandlers`, as documented by MS themselves [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming)

Comment: `async void`  was created for the use cases when it needs to be used for event handling where the signature must be `void` and can't be `Task`

Comment: Move `Init()` call to `Form.Load` Event handler, don't call it externally. Make `Form2_Load` `async`, change `Init()` to `async Task` and call `await Init()` then.