# Appending to file inside an async method called by timer

Tags: c#, async-await, streamwriter

I'm trying to use

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(filePath))
{
    sw.WriteLine(n.InnerText);
}
```

inside a method which has I think must be async, because it's calling a await on an async method `GetByteArrayAsync()`

**PollSite Function:**

```cs
private async void PollSite(string filePath, string siteURL)
{
    response = await http.GetByteArrayAsync(siteURL);
    source = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(Encoding
        .GetEncoding("utf-8")
        .GetString(response, 0, response.Length - 1));
    result = new HtmlDocument();
    result.LoadHtml(source);

    gNode = result.GetElementbyId("SomeTable");

    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(filePath))
    {
        foreach (HtmlNode n in gNode.Descendants("td"))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(n.InnerText);
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to write gives me the error:

> The process cannot access the file '`filePath`' because it is being
> used by another process.

I'm assuming this is because of the async calls, but have no idea how to get round this and achieve the file write - is it because of the `using` statement?

Comment: Are you sure the file located at `filePath` isn't opened by another part of the application, or another application entirely? The way you're using StreamWriter in the provided code should be fine.

Comment: This has nothing to do with it being async, its exactly as the error says - you cant write to the path as something (probably your own program) is already using it - you're probably forgetting somewhere else to close the write stream

Comment: [`async void` is wrong, this should be `async Task`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45447955/why-exactly-is-void-async-bad)

Comment: When you call the method regularly (aka you are polling) do you call the method with await? I asume you are polling without waiting (awaiting) for the method and you have multiple PollSite methods running in parallel.

Comment: To clarify what Liam and Ralf are getting at; if you don't `await` this method (i.e. make it return a `Task`) you could fire the method multiple times, all whilst looking at the same file and thus have multiple processes trying to write to the same file.

Comment: Ahh guys, thank you, it was because right at the start outside of these threads I'd used `File.Create("MyFilePath");` - if I comment that out, it works fine so I guess `File.Create` keeps the file open and I need to close it somehow.

Comment: [Avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void).

Answer (score 0):

Just make a semaphore and wait.

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _gate = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

private async void PollSite(string filePath, string siteURL)
{
    response = await http.GetByteArrayAsync(siteURL);
    source = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(Encoding
        .GetEncoding("utf-8")
        .GetString(response, 0, response.Length - 1));
    result = new HtmlDocument();
    result.LoadHtml(source);

    var gNode = result.GetElementbyId("SomeTable");
    await _gate.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        using (var sw = File.AppendText(filePath))
        {
            foreach (var n in gNode.Descendants("td"))
            {
                 sw.WriteLine(n.InnerText);
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        _gate.Release();
    }
}
```