# Why does user interface still freeze?

Tags: c#, multithreading, xaml, async-await

I'm trying to prevent freezing application interface at waiting moment, so I code this function, but it doesn't work.

Where is the mistake, and how can I solve this?

```
async void buttonBlocking()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        if (irTryCounter % 3 == 0)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                grdLogin.IsEnabled = false;
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                grdLogin.IsEnabled = true;
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you can as well use `async/await` in lambda for invoke with `Task.Delay`, but that's weird. Use timer?

Comment: `this.Dispatcher.Invoke()` will run that code in the context of the UI thread, so the sleep will be stopping the UI thread.

Comment: Also [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45447955/1997232).

Comment: In addition to @MatthewWatson's fine comment, please note that `Dispatcher.Invoke` can lead to deadlock not only for the UI thread but also for the thread pool thread.  For this reason consider using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`.  Of course you will want to move that `Thread.Sleep` elsewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `buttonBlocking` is invoked from UI thread, then you can simplify your code:

```cs
async void buttonBlocking()
{
  if (irTryCounter % 3 == 0)
  {
    grdLogin.IsEnabled = false;
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    grdLogin.IsEnabled = true;
  }
}
```

This way it won't block your UI

Comment: Don't do `async void` - always do `async Task` unless if is an event handler.

Answer (score -1):

The mistake, as pointed by Matthew Watson in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68017238/why-does-user-interface-still-freeze/68017706#comment120218376_68017238), is that the `Dispatcher.Invoke()` will run the code on the UI thread, so the `Thread.Sleep` will be blocking the UI thread.

Now let's see how this problem can be fixed. I am assuming that your code is an event handler, and you want this handler to run asynchronously. This is the only valid scenario for using an [`async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) method. In any other case you should use `async Task`.

```
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (irTryCounter % 3 == 0)
    {
        grdLogin.IsEnabled = false;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // Here you can run any code that takes a long time to complete
            // Any interaction with UI controls is forbidden here
            // This code will run on the thread-pool, not on the UI thread
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        });
        grdLogin.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

In case the long-running operation returns a result that needs to be passed to the UI thread, use the `Task.Run` overload that returns a `Task<TResult>`:

```
int result = await Task.Run(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    return 13;
});
// We are back on the UI thread, and the result is available for presentation
```

I am assuming that the `Thread.Sleep(10000)` is a placeholder for an actual synchronous operation that takes a long time to complete. It would be even better if this operation can be performed asynchronously, because it would not require consuming a `ThreadPool` thread for the whole duration of the operation. As an example, a delay can be performed asynchronously by using the `Task.Delay` method:

```
await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(10000);
});
```

In this case the `Task.Run` wrapper may seem redundant, but actually [it's not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739403/await-task-run-vs-await-c-sharp/58306020#58306020). Wrapping your asynchronous code in a `Task.Run` protects your application from badly behaving asynchronous APIs that block the current thread. The overhead of including the wrapper is minuscule, and should have no noticeable effect in a WinForms/WPF application. The exception is ASP.NET applications, where `Task.Run`ing is inadvisable.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer, I think it reads much better now with the detailed explanation and I particularly like the walkthrough style.. :)