# System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Instances cannot be resolved and nested lifetimes cannot be created from this LifetimeScope

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac, cqrs, mediatr

I have an async controller and I am trying to call two different Async functions from it. like this

```
   public async void Approvefiles(string[] data)
    {

       var response = await _mediator.Send(new persons.Query(data));
       await _mediator.Send(new employees.Query(data));

    }
```

All looks good to me, But this throws an error

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Instances cannot be resolved and nested lifetimes cannot be created from this LifetimeScope as it has already been disposed.'
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here? And this error doesn't occur if I call only one async function (for exaple persons.Query only).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```cs
 public async void Approvefiles(string[] data)
```

`async void` methods pretty much means that nothing will wait for that method to finish before continuing (as well as causing a host of other problems).

So I imagine your request scope is getting cleaned up before your second `_mediator.Send` call, meaning nothing can be resolved.

You need to change the signature to:

```cs
public async Task Approvefiles(string[] data)
```

Then await that method as needed in your controller to make sure it completes before your request ends.

There's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45448104/114400) about why async void is bad, for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents. Mine was a petty mistake, I forgot to await an async call.

So I had this async extension method as follows.

```cs
public static async Task<T> DeserializePostInMeWurkFormat<T>(this HttpClient httpClient, string route, HttpContent? content)
{
  var postResult = await httpClient.PostAsync(route, content);
  postResult.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  postResult.IsSuccessStatusCode.Should().BeTrue();
  var stringResponse = await postResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  var response = stringResponse.DeserializeWithCamelCasePolicy<T>();
  return response!;
}
```

And I was calling without awaiting it as follows.

```cs
var postsResult = _client.DeserializePostInMeWurkFormat<CompanyOnboardDto>(OnboardCompanyRequest.Route, data);
```

Got the exception as follows.

> System.ObjectDisposedException
> HResult=0x80131622
> Message=Instances cannot be resolved and nested lifetimes cannot be created from this LifetimeScope as it (or one of its parent scopes) has already been disposed.
> Source=Autofac

Corrected the call as follows with await, and now it works fine.

```cs
var postsResult = await _client.DeserializePostInMeWurkFormat<CompanyOnboardDto>(OnboardCompanyRequest.Route, data);
```