# Updating a static field by passing it as a method argument

Tags: c#, static-methods, helper

My app will involve a lot of modifying of static fields. I'm wondering how to update the static fields from different classes by passing them as a method argument to a utility setter method.

```
internal static class Hero1
{
  public static bool awesomeAbility = false;
  public static bool anotherAwesomeAbility = false;
}

internal static class Hero2
{
  public static bool awesomeAbility = false;
  public static bool anotherAwesomeAbility = false;
}

internal static class Utils
{
  public static async void ToggleAbility(ability, bool value)
  {
    Logger.Write($@"{ability} = {value}");
    ability = value;
  }
}

// example usage....
ToggleAbility(Hero1.awesomeAbility, true);
ToggleAbility(Hero2.anotherAwesomeAbility, false);
```

Comment: While this is possible, I don't think "a lot of modifying of static fields" is a good design in the first place.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but this is an existing project that has a lot of this already. I'm trying to simplify one aspect of it by cleaning up all the redundant toggle methods for each ability and put them into one that can receive the ability as a method argument. The reason I describe it as an async method is because often the abilities are set back to their original state based on a dynamic amount of miliseconds. The current obstacle for me is just figuring out how to pass and modify the static fields to this utility method.

Comment: If you make a static field public you can update it from virtually any piece of code that references the assembly ;) The usual OOP-way is to have a method or property on the class itself, that controls how, by whom, when etc it can being updated. They call it encapsulation. It's one of the core prinicpals of object-oruented programming. But nonethelesse you can code by any paradigm you like.

Comment: @lidqy how do i define the method parameter to accept any type of static field?

Comment: If you want to make sure the field itself is updated and avoid copying "by value" the you need to pass it by refernce using the "ref" keyword on the method paramater.
If concurrent access/race conditions are an issue, you need to implkement some kind of locking/synchronisation .

Comment: @user999666 the value of static field can be passed to a method just as a non-satic field's value or wahtever varaible.
However you need to make sure that the method changes the orginla value and not the copyl, which it will most of the time since .NET passed by value by default.

Comment: Does it need to be `async void`? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45447955/why-exactly-is-void-async-bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this if you allow the caller to pass an expression tree (`Expression<Func<bool>>`), then you can get the field referenced by the expression tree as a `FieldInfo`.

```
async void ToggleAbility(Expression<Func<bool>> field, bool value) {
    if (field.Body is MemberExpression memberExpression &&
        memberExpression.Member is FieldInfo fieldInfo) {
        
        // instead of field.Body, you can also use fieldInfo.Name for a simple name
        Logger.Write($@"{field.Body} = {fieldInfo.GetValue(null)}");

        // this sets the field's value
        fieldInfo.SetValue(null, value);

        // if you want to set it back asynchronously some time later...
        // await Task.Delay(...);
        // fieldInfo.SetValue(null, !value);
    } else {
        // the expression tree is not an access to a public static field
        // you could e.g. throw an exception 
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ToggleAbility(() => Hero1.awesomeAbility, true);
```

Setting a field with `SetValue` is not very fast. If that is a problem for you, you can take a "field setter" `Action<bool>`

```
async void ToggleAbility(Action<bool> setter, bool value) {
    setter(value)
    await Task.Delay(...);
    setter(!vakue)
}
```

```
ToggleAbility(x => Hero1.awesomeAbility = x, true);
```

However, you cannot access the field name or its current value in `ToggleAbility` with this approach, unless you also pass them in as additional parameters:

```
ToggleAbility(
    x => Hero1.awesomeAbility = x, 
    true,
    nameof(Hero1.awesomeAbility),
    Hero1.awesomeAbility);
```

If your method doesn't need to be async, you can also pass the field in as a `ref` parameter, as lidqy's answer shows.

Comment: This is both awesome as it is incredibly slow and needs loads of code for the plain simple task to assign a value to a field ;)

Comment: How about: `async void ToggleAbility(Action<bool> setter, bool value)  => setter(value);` invoked as: `await ToggleAbility( val => Hero1.awesomeAbility = val, true);`

Comment: And in the end, why not just do: `Hero1.awesomeAbility = true` ?

Comment: @lidqy OP seems to be extracting some common logic into this `ToggleAbility` method - it doesn't just set the field. Taking an `Action<bool>` does work - I just personally don't like rewriting `= val` all the time. Perhaps I should add that in as an alternative.

Comment: @lidqy Actually, just taking an `Action` wouldn't work because OP wants to access the name and value of the field in the method.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you need the `ref` keyword in order to actually change the field's value in the owning class (static or not). Else you just change the copy which is dicared once the method has been invoked.

However it can no longer be async then.

```
internal static class Utils
{
  public static void ToggleAbility(ref bool ability, bool value)
  {
    Logger.Write($@"{ability} = {value}");
    ability = value;
  }
}

ToggleAbility(ref Hero1.awesomeAbility, true);
ToggleAbility(ref Hero2.anotherAwesomeAbility, false);
```