An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
I'm not understanding why I'm getting an error while trying to add a product to a cart in my DB. I have a product that I want to add to cart. If a cart does not exist then we create a new cart and add it to the db. Every time we add the same product it should increase the count by 1. It should populate the cart with said product but I get an Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Invalid operation. The connection is closed.' error message. ASP.NET Core MVC 8
ShoppingCartController.cs

    private readonly ILogger<ShoppingCartController> _logger;
    private readonly DBContext _dbContext;
    private const string CartSessionKey = "CartId";
    private string ShoppingCartId { get; set;}

    public ShoppingCartController(ILogger<ShoppingCartController> logger, DBContext dBContext)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _dbContext = dBContext;
    }

    public async void AddToCart(int id)
    {
        ShoppingCartId = GetCartID();
        // Bottom line code breaks with the InvalidOperationException
        Cart cart = await _dbContext.Carts.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.CartId == ShoppingCartId && c.ProductId == id);
        if (cart == null)
        {
            // If cart is null then we create a new cart
            Cart newCart = new Cart
            {
                ProductId = id,
                CartId = ShoppingCartId,
                Product = await _dbContext.Products.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ProductId == id),
                Count = 1,
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
            };

            await _dbContext.Carts.AddAsync(newCart);
        }
        else
        {
            cart.Count++;
        }

        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    private string GetCartID()
    {
        if(HttpContext.Session.Keys.Contains(CartSessionKey) == false)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name))
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetString(CartSessionKey,HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            }
            else
            { 
                Guid tempCartId = Guid.NewGuid();
                HttpContext.Session.SetString(CartSessionKey, tempCartId.ToString());
            }
        }

        return HttpContext.Session.GetString(CartSessionKey);
    }
}


Dashboard.cshtml

<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="row rows-cols-4">
        @foreach(var prod in @ViewBag.Products)
        {
            <div class="card m-1" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">@prod.ProductName</h5>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="Customer" asp-action="ProductDetails" asp-route-id="@prod.ProductId">More Details</a>
                    // This is where it would add the product to cart
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="ShoppingCart" asp-action="AddToCart" asp-route-id="@prod.ProductId">Add to cart</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        
    </div>
</div>


Cart.cs

public class Cart
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }

    public string CartId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}



Could you provide your Carts model? It seems a bit strange that a Cart would only ever be able to hold a single product type? Also, you should be using _dbContext.Carts.Add(newCart); not the async version as stated in EF documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addasync?view=efcore-8.0

akseli's answer basically covers the main issue for the exception, that you have it declared as async void instead of async Task. There are few if any good reasons to ever use async void and you absolutely never want to use async void for a controller action. If you have a void synchronous method to make async use async Task. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45447955/why-exactly-is-async-void-considered-bad-practice for more info.

You have a few issues that should be addressed:

According to Microsoft's EF documentation here you should be using:

_dBContext.Carts.Add(newCart);

and not AddAsync(). AddAsync should only be used in very specific circumstances when you have special sql generators that require async access to your database.

Async methods should never return void, they should always return a Task. So, your method signature should look like this:

public async Task AddToCart(int id)

It seems that, because of your async void, EF was closing your DBContext Connection early, which was throwing the exception above.

Not convinced about the 1 point that you have mentioned as the link directly sent me to using AddAsync and after reviewing both Add and AddAsync I don't see why I need to switch that line of code. For the 2 point that makes much more sense. Switch public async void to public async Task and it no longer gives me the error.

If you check the Remarks section of the documentation it states: “ This method is async only to allow special value generators, such as the one used by 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo', to access the database asynchronously. For all other cases the non async method should be used.”

Ah I see it now. I overlooked that paragraph
